# Using Terraform to create a Service Fabric cluster issues

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use Terraform to create a Service fabric cluster in Azure.

I have created configurations for the follwoing resources using a template provided by Tvo  https://github.com/TrevorVonSeggern/ServiceFabric_Terraform

This will create the reasorces in Azure however the SFC just sits on "Deploying" and the Nodes themselves never display.

There seems to be a distinct lack of configuration resources for creating a Service fabric cluster using Terraform and HashiCorp's documentation on this resource example is not as in depth as for other resources.

Provisioning with Powershell is easier as more resources to guide.

If anyone has any working examples please can you share them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to deploy this successfully by deploying and then going through the extensions in the ARM template. Then adding (in JSON string) in the Terraform config for VMSS

Could not find anywhere in the Terraform documentation on this resource to assist with this.

Comment: Can you please show the steps what you did to configure node in sfc. I need it too.